# Angular2 : Input binding

Tags: angular

I am trying to bind the input with the component as defined here :

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child
but **component name is never shown**

I am even trying to do the console.log but it shows:

> componentName isundefined

```
<div ng-switch="accessLevel">
<div class="customer" ng-switch-when="ENABLED">This is customer data</div>
<div class="customer-blurr"  ng-switch-when="DISABLED"> This is disabled Customer Data</div>
<div class="customer-blurr" ng-switch-default> <demo-error [componentName]="componentname"></demo-error></div>
</div>
```

and in **error.html**

```
<div> you are not allowed to access {{component}} </div>
```

**Demo Error :**

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-error',
  templateUrl: './error.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./error.component.css']
})
export class ErrorComponentDemo implements OnInit {
@Input() public componentName:string;
  constructor() { 
    console.log("componentName is" +this.componentName)
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

}

```
And in **CustomerComponent:**

@Component({
  selector: 'customer',
  templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer.component.css']
})
export class CustomerComponent extends SuperChildComponent{
  public allowed: boolean = false;
  public  accessLevel:AccessLevel =null;
  public componentname:string;

  constructor(private authenticationService : AuthorizationService) {
    super();
    this.componentname=this.constructor.name;
     this.accessLevel=this.authenticationService.isUserLoggedIn()?this.authenticationService.componentAccessLevel(this.constructor.name):null;
  }
```

what am i missing here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input won't be available in the constructor yet. Try this f.e.

```
@Input set componentName(value: string) { 
  if(value != null && value != undefined) {
    this._componentName = value; console.log(this._componentName); 
  }
}

_componentName: string
```

This way you can do your calls of methods in the `if` statement within the `set`

Answer (score 2):

You need to lose the '[]' if your input is a string.

```
componentName="componentname"
```